# Why is there initial delay for showing bitmap

Tags: android, handler

I'm trying to translate a `Bitmap` so i just update it's x and y so it moves diagonally to learn about threads, but the problem is when app starts, the `Bitmap` doesn't show up and I noticed the delay is tied to the time I set in the handler's postDelayed method but I thought this postDelayed method was supposed to only control how fast the bitmap moves across the screen and not the delay for the bitmap just showing up when I open the app.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Canvas canvas;
InnerView innerView;
Handler mHandler;
Bitmap thisBitmap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    thisBitmap =
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.my_image);

    mHandler = new Handler();
    innerView = new InnerView(this);
    setContentView( innerView);
}

class InnerView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    Thread ourThread = null;
    SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
    Paint paint;
    int posX = 100;
    int posY = 100;

    public InnerView (Context context) {
        super(context);
        ourHolder = getHolder();
        paint = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        update
        draw();
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
     }

    public void update() {
       posX += 10;
       posY += 10;
    }

    public void draw() {
        if (ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
            canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();

            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);//the background
            paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
            canvas.drawBitmap( goodDotList[0], posX, posY, paint);
            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }

   }//END inner class: InnerView


}//END MainActivity class
```

Comment: you don't draw your bitmap on screen initially. You draw it only on handler. So before your handler is called, the bitmap won't be drawn.

Comment: I added innerView.draw() inside the end of onCreate and still there is delay ...i don't know

Comment: it doesn't work still because during `onCreate` the `ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()` still returns false. Add it on the surfaceCreated event.

Comment: How do I make a big post again like the first post when I hit the Ask Question button because it's annoying when I press Enter it posts the comment

Comment: there is a button labeled `Ask Question`